# SAML SSO authentication using Spring Boot 3 and ADFS

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, java-17, spring-boot-3

I'm looking for a working example of SAML 2.0 SSO Authentication using Spring boot 3 and ADFS as IDP in non cloud environment. I Went through many samples and tutorials but to be honest most of them are reprint of spring-boot-3 SAML Authentication tutorial which itself is not clear enough. Please share any example or test code if someone has went through similar problem statement. TIA.

I tried with below Spring boot example and SAML config, wherein changed the URL for assertingparty.metadata-uri with adfs uri

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/saml-extension-federation/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-security-saml-test-identity-provider-and-service-provider check this out. I've implemented SP initiated SSO flow with Spring Boot 3.